# Flutter - Align bottom doesn't reach bottom

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, layout, alignment

This is the home page of my app, here I use column to display the page's content: container with Anime of the day and stories scroll container.

By default, everything is OK, but, when I scroll stories (ListView), a crack appears (see attachments), so the gradient doesn't reach the end. What is the problem?

Screenshots:

[Before scroll](https://s3.image.hosting/2021/05/27/vebD.jpg)

[After scroll](https://s3.image.hosting/2021/05/27/vMUB.jpg)

Code snippet:

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
            height: 510,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
              Positioned.fill(
                  child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                            'https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/nbig/3/59/shingeki-no-kyojin-ataka-titanov-parni-eren-levi.jpg'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              )),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 510,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                            Color(0x15161a),
                            Color(0x2d15161a),
                            Color(0xff18191e)
                          ],
                              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                              end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text('Вторжение титанов',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontSize: 40,
                                    )),
                                SizedBox(height: 5),
                                Text(
                                  'Attack of titans',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 80),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'приключения',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 16,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '2021',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 16,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '18+',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                )
                              ]))))
            ])),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 11,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 37,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffdddddd),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 36,
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1f23),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 34,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://picsum.photos/200/300'),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Новое',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 11,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 9,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 37,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffdddddd),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 36,
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1f23),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 34,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://picsum.photos/200/300'),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Новое',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 11,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 9,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 37,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffdddddd),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 36,
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1f23),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 34,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://picsum.photos/200/300'),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Новое',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 11,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 9,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 37,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffdddddd),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 36,
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1f23),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 34,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://picsum.photos/200/300'),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Новое',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 11,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 9,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 37,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffdddddd),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 36,
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1f23),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 34,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://picsum.photos/200/300'),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Новое',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 11,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 9,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 37,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xffdddddd),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 36,
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff1e1f23),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 34,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://picsum.photos/200/300'),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Новое',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 11,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ]),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 37,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(11, 0, 0, 11),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                'Новинки',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Add `margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:1)` this to your `Container()` inside `Positioned.fill()` do the trick now that artifact line won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:1)` to `Container()` inside `Positioned.fill()` solved the problem.

Solution by @ChiragBargoojar